# How to refuse reserved instance that is in payment-pending status?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have been playing with AWS console and I have requested a reserved instance. I have not had enough funds on my credit card, so the status of the reserved instance is still "payment-pending".

Now I want to refuse this reserved instance and I can't find out how to do this neither in AWS console, nor by CLI tools.

Answer (score 5):

You need to get in touch with AWS billing department asking to cancel the pending reserved instance, here:

https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/aws-account-and-billing

It seems not to be possible to cancel using the AWS console.

Comment: Yep. "The charges for Reserved Instances are not automatically retried. We only retry charges for Reserved Instance purchases at the explicit request of the customer." [AWS Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=201537)